# how to get last request time in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I want to get last and current request time using servlet.

I have a web page in my application, in that page I want to get last request time. If the user not do any action for some minutes. after some times user do some action in that page that time I want to get current time.

With these I want to check some condition.

I just give idea what I want to do....

```
idletime = current request time - last request time

if (ideltime > 2mins)
{
  redirect to logout page;
} 
else
{
allow to work;
}
```

This is what I want to do.

Comment: A fairly simple way of doing this is to set the session timeout in the servlet container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!-- use this Syntax in web.xml file in wepaap folder within <web-app> </web-app>  -->

<session-config>
  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

Comment: you should use this tags in web.xml file within <web-app> <session-config>
  <session-timeout>15</session-timeout> 
</session-config>   </web-app> whatever time you need to set(like i was used 15 )